# Extending Banach Space of Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

The idea is that one could in principle consider the space of functions:
$$\{f:\Omega\to V\}$$
with pointwise operations and uniform convergence:
$$f_\lambda\to f:\iff\|f_\lambda-f\|_\infty\to 0$$

---

Given a Banach space of functions:
$$E:=\{f:\Omega\to V:\|f\|\text{ exists}\}$$
with $\Omega$ a suitable space and $V$ a vector space.

This then gives rise to a topological vector space.
(It has special properties due to its construction via a norm.)

Now, in principle this could be extended to:
$$E_\infty:=\{f:\Omega\to V\}$$
with the same vector space structure but with new topology as follows.

Define a neighborhood base by:
$$B_\varepsilon(f):=\{f'\in E_\infty:f'-f\in E,\|f'-f\|<\varepsilon\}$$
Does it give rise to a topological vector space?

Comment: Is $B_\varepsilon(0)$ absorbing then?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ahaaah :D no it isn't I mean not necessarily... so it can't be a tvs, right? In other words scalar multiplication becomes discontinuous

Comment: @DanielFischer: Do you want to put an answer yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E_\infty$ contains unbounded functions (without any continuity or similar requirements on the functions, that means $\Omega$ is infinite), then the topology of uniform convergence is not a vector space topology on $E_\infty$. One sees that then the balls around $0$, $B_\varepsilon(0)$, are not absorbing, hence the scalar multiplication is not continuous. $E_\infty$ is still a topological group in the topology of uniform convergence, however.